# For loop crashes my program?

Tags: c

For whatever reason the `for` loop in `getLetters` causes a crash.

I haven't been able to single out a specific source within it, maybe someone could help?

I think I might have done my pointers incorrectly. How should I fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>


int main() {
    FILE *ifp;
    ifp = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");
    int* lValues[26];
    int* lDist[26];
    int* lUsed[26];
    int*fRun = 0;
    int dictLen;
    int i;
    int bestValue;
    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &dictLen);
    char bestWord[7];
    char dictionary[dictLen][7];
    char* letters[7];
    char* userWord[7];

    //reads the dictionary into the array
    for (i = 0; i < dictLen; i++) {
        fscanf(ifp, "%s", &dictionary[i]);
    }

    distribution();
    values();

    while (i != 2) {

        getLetters();

        printf("Welcome to the Scrabble Practice Program!\n");
        printf("\nHere are your letters: %s \n", letters);
        printf("\nWhat would you like to do?\n");
        printf("\t1-Enter Word\n");
        printf("\t2-Quit\n\n");
        printf("User Selection:");
        scanf("%d", &i);
    }

    //fclose(ifp); not sure why, but this crashes the program

    return 0;
}

//Gets the user's set of letters
void getLetters() {
    char* letters[7];
    int* lDist[26];
    int* lUsed[26];
    int lCur;
    int i;

    srand(time(0));

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

        *letters[i] = 65 + rand()%26;
        lCur = (int)*letters[i] - 65;

        while (*lUsed[lCur] >= *lDist[lCur]){

            *letters[i] = 65 + rand()%26;
            lCur = (int)*letters[i] - 65;
        }

        *lUsed[lCur]++;
    }
}

//Sets the number of each letter available for distribution
void distribution() {
    int* lDist;

    //Number for A
    lDist[0] = 9;

    //Number for B
    lDist[1] = 2;

    //Number for C
    lDist[2] = 2;

    //Number for D
    lDist[3] = 4;

    //Number for E
    lDist[4] = 12;

    //Number for F
    lDist[5] = 2;

    //Number for G
    lDist[6] = 3;

    //Number for H
    lDist[7] = 2;

    //Number for I
    lDist[8] = 9;

    //Number for J
    lDist[9] = 1;

    //Number for K
    lDist[10] = 1;

    //Number for L
    lDist[11] = 4;

    //Number for M
    lDist[12] = 2;

    //Number for N
    lDist[13] = 6;

    //Number for O
    lDist[14] = 8;

    //Number for P
    lDist[15] = 2;

    //Number for Q
    lDist[16] = 1;

    //Number for R
    lDist[17] = 6;

    //Number for S
    lDist[18] = 4;

    //Number for T
    lDist[19] = 6;

    //Number for U
    lDist[20] = 4;

    //Number for V
    lDist[21] = 2;

    //Number for W
    lDist[22] = 2;

    //Number for X
    lDist[23] = 1;

    //Number for Y
    lDist[24] = 2;

    //Number for Z
    lDist[25] = 1;
}


//Sets the value of all of the letters
void values() {

    int* lValues;

    //Value of A
    lValues[0] = 1;

    //Value of B
    lValues[1] = 3;

    //Value of C
    lValues[2] = 3;

    //Value of D
    lValues[3] = 2;

    //Value of E
    lValues[4] = 1;

    //Value of F
    lValues[5] = 4;

    //Value of G
    lValues[6] = 2;

    //Value of H
    lValues[7] = 4;

    //Value of I
    lValues[8] = 1;

    //Value of J
    lValues[9] = 8;

    //Value of K
    lValues[10] = 5;

    //Value of L
    lValues[11] = 1;

    //Value of M
    lValues[12] = 3;

    //Value of N
    lValues[13] = 1;

    //Value of O
    lValues[14] = 1;

    //Value of P
    lValues[15] = 3;

    //Value of Q
    lValues[16] = 10;

    //Value of R
    lValues[17] = 1;

    //Value of S
    lValues[18] = 1;

    //Value of T
    lValues[19] = 1;

    //Value of U
    lValues[20] = 1;

    //Value of V
    lValues[21] = 4;

    //Value of W
    lValues[22] = 4;

    //Value of X
    lValues[23] = 8;

    //Value of Y
    lValues[24] = 4;

    //Value of Z
    lValues[25] = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
*letters[i] = 65 + rand()%26;
```

letter[i] refers nowhere meaningful(uninitialized) and you can end up with `Access violation fault`.

Further

```
char* letters[7];
int* lDist[26];
int* lUsed[26];
```

all of them are `arrays of pointer` and not the array of basic types(ie. int,char etc.).I think you probably wanted

```
char letters[7];//Array of seven characters
int lDist[26];//Array of 26 ints
int lUsed[26];//Array of 26 ints
```

and start referring `*letters[i]` simply as `letters[i]`

Comment: Well, this is only a portion of a program, those pointers are ued elsewhere

Comment: @user1669299:- So you should first initialize your pointers like `char* letters[7]; letters[0]="string one"` (NOTE:this is bad initialization in your case, use suitable one for yourself)etc.

Comment: I updated the post so, now it shows the entire code, each char in the array should be filled with a random letter when running through the function.

Answer (score 1):

`letters`, `lDist` and `lUsed` are arrays of pointers (which aren't initialized). Why don't you use arrays instead?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void getLetters(void)
{
    char letters[7];
    int lDist[26];
    int lUsed[26];
    int lCur;
    int i;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        letters[i] = 65 + rand() % 26;
        lCur = (int) letters[i] - 65;

        while (lUsed[lCur] >= lDist[lCur]) {
            letters[i] = 65 + rand() % 26;
            lCur = (int) letters[i] - 65;
        }

        lUsed[lCur]++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every single array access in your `getLetters` function can cause a problem: you declare three arrays of pointers that are never initialized, so any time you dereference an element of any of the arrays you are dereferencing a garbage memory address, and sometimes trying to write to that memory address.

From your code it's unclear why you need arrays of *pointers*.

Why not simply:

```
char letters[7];
int lDist[26];
int lUsed[26];
```

And get rid of the dereferencing?

But even then, the function has problems. You'll need to initialize your array values, at least `lDist` and `lUsed`. You compare against elements of `lDist` but otherwise never change those values.

Comment: I updated the original post with the full program, I use pointers because I need to re use those values in main(), how would I set all of the vaules in lUsed to 0 other than setting them each individually?

Answer (score 1):

It does not appear that the above code does what you intend it to do. When you declare the variable

```
char* letters[7];
```

… you're declaring an array of 7 `char *`s, not 7 `char`s. Thus, when you say

```
*letters[i] = 65 + rand()%26;
```

… you first index into the array and retrieve the pointer at index `i`. You then dereference that pointer and try to store a character there. The problem is that `letters` is never initialized, and is most likely filled with junk: for any value `i`, `letters[i]` will return a random value. Thus, when you try to dereference that as an address, you are indexing into someone else's memory, and writing to it will cause a segmentation fault.

It seems that you meant to declare `letters` (and `lDist` and `lUsed`) like so:

```
char letters[7];
int lDist[26];
int lUsed[26];
```

That means an array of `char`s with length 7. You would then address them without dereferencing:

```
letters[i] = 65 + rand()%26;
```

You could also do the above as…

```
*(letters + i) = 65 + rand()%26;
```

… but you generally don't mean to mix the two together.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use pointers, use plain arrays will do, like this (I also added initialization for lUsed and lDist):

```
void getLetters() {
    char letters[7];
    int lDist[26];
    int lUsed[26];
    int lCur;
    int i;


    srand(time(0));

    // initialize the arrays
    for (i=0;i<26;i++) {
        lUsed[i] = lDist[i] = 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

        letters[i] = 65 + rand()%26;
        lCur = (int)letters[i] - 65;

        while (lUsed[lCur] >= lDist[lCur]){

            letters[i] = 65 + rand()%26;
            lCur = (int)letters[i] - 65;

        }

        lUsed[lCur]++;

    }
}
```